# JasperDesign object VS. Dynamicreports VS. DynamicJasper

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper, dynamic-reports

I'm a newbie in Jasper reports, did some research and found three options for Dynamic report creation:

1) JasperDesign Object of Jasper reports Library
2) DynamicJasper
3) Dynamicreports

What ares pros and cons or differences between these options. I need to start my project As soon as possible.
I would appreciate your help to get a better overview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of what you are trying to do, [**Dynamic Jasper**](http://dynamicjasper.com/) could be the best option:

- It has a lot of examples and docs
  (you have test sources, that you can find them in the bundle, to test all examples they give you)
- Make released very often 
  (You have released from JR 3.5 to JR 6.0)
- It easier and you need less code to write a dynamic reports, compared to using JR capabilities
- I have seen more usage of [Dynamic Jasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/) than [**Dynamic Reports**](http://www.dynamicreports.org/)

I wouldn't use [**Jasper Design**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) object if I were newbie or I were not used to working with the JR's API.

Comment: I already created one with Dynamic Report and found it pretty much flexible but documentation is poor.  I like the short coding style and builders. thanks for extensive info.